# Qual o melhor jeito de enviar um formulário?

Tags: php, ajax, envio-de-email

Bom dia,

preciso fazer o envio do formulário que for preenchido, na página tenho vários formulários e que apenas tenho que enviar o que vai ser preenchido. Gostaria de saber se o melhor jeito é fazer cada id para cada formulário e também um arquivo php para cada formulário?

HTML:

```
<form class="head-quote-seguro" method="post">
    <p class="pclasse">formulario 1</p>
    <input type="hidden" nome="seguro" id="seguro" value="Seguro 1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quote-name" id="quote-name" placeholder="Nome" required />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quote-name" id="quote-name" placeholder="Nome" required />
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="quote-email" id="quote-email" placeholder="Email" required />
    <input type="text" class="form-control tel" name="quote-telephone" id="quote-telephone" placeholder="Telefone"
        required />
    <textarea class="form-control" name="quote-message" id="quote-message" placeholder="O que precisa?" rows="2"
        required></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-black btn-block">Enviar</button>
    <!--Alert Message-->
    <div id="head-quote-result" class="mt-xs">
    </div>
</form>

<form class="head-quote-seguro" method="post">
    <p class="pclasse">formulario 2</p>
    <input type="hidden" nome="seguro" id="seguro" value="Seguro 2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quote-name" id="quote-name" placeholder="Nome" required />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quote-name" id="quote-name" placeholder="Nome" required />
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="quote-email" id="quote-email" placeholder="Email" required />
    <input type="text" class="form-control tel" name="quote-telephone" id="quote-telephone" placeholder="Telefone"
        required />
    <textarea class="form-control" name="quote-message" id="quote-message" placeholder="O que precisa?" rows="2"
        required></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-black btn-block">Enviar</button>
    <!--Alert Message-->
    <div id="head-quote-result" class="mt-xs">
    </div>
</form>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(function () {
    var frm = $(".head-quote-seguro");
    frm.submit(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./form-seguros.php",
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function () {
                $(".head-quote-seguro").append("<div class='alert alert-success'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>×</button><i class='fa fa-thumbs-o-up'></i><strong>Obrigado!</strong> Sua mensagem foi enviada!</div>")
            }
        }), e.preventDefault()
    }), jQuery(".tap-title").each(function () {
        jQuery(this).on('click', function () {
            return jQuery(this).parent().parent().hasClass("toggle-accordion") ? (jQuery(this).parent().find("li:first .tap-title").addClass("active"), jQuery(this).parent().find("li:first .tap-title").next(".accordion-inner").addClass("active"), jQuery(this).toggleClass("active"), jQuery(this).next(".accordion-inner").slideToggle().toggleClass("active"), jQuery(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-plus").toggleClass("fa-minus")) : jQuery(this).next().is(":hidden") ? (jQuery(this).parent().parent().find(".tap-title").removeClass("active").next().slideUp(200), jQuery(this).parent().parent().find(".tap-title").next().removeClass("active").slideUp(200), jQuery(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideDown(200), jQuery(this).next(".accordion-inner").toggleClass("active"), jQuery(this).parent().parent().find("i").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus"), jQuery(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus")) : (jQuery(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(200), jQuery(this).next(".accordion-inner").toggleClass("active"), jQuery(this).parent().parent().find("i").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus")), !1
        })
    });     
});


$(function () {
    var frm = $(".head-quote-form");
    frm.submit(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./form-seguros.php",
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function () {
                $(".head-quote-form").append("<div class='alert alert-success'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>×</button><i class='fa fa-thumbs-o-up'></i><strong>Obrigado!</strong> Sua mensagem foi enviada!</div>")
            }
        }), e.preventDefault()
    }), jQuery(".tap-title").each(function () {
        jQuery(this).on('click', function () {
            return jQuery(this).parent().parent().hasClass("toggle-accordion") ? (jQuery(this).parent().find("li:first .tap-title").addClass("active"), jQuery(this).parent().find("li:first .tap-title").next(".accordion-inner").addClass("active"), jQuery(this).toggleClass("active"), jQuery(this).next(".accordion-inner").slideToggle().toggleClass("active"), jQuery(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-plus").toggleClass("fa-minus")) : jQuery(this).next().is(":hidden") ? (jQuery(this).parent().parent().find(".tap-title").removeClass("active").next().slideUp(200), jQuery(this).parent().parent().find(".tap-title").next().removeClass("active").slideUp(200), jQuery(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideDown(200), jQuery(this).next(".accordion-inner").toggleClass("active"), jQuery(this).parent().parent().find("i").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus"), jQuery(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus")) : (jQuery(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(200), jQuery(this).next(".accordion-inner").toggleClass("active"), jQuery(this).parent().parent().find("i").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus")), !1
        })
    });     
});
```

PHP:

```
<script language= "JavaScript">
setTimeout("document.location = http://ninerscorretora.com.br",1000);
</script>

    <?php
    // Check for empty fields
    if(empty($_POST['quote-name']) || empty($_POST['quote-telephone']) || empty($_POST['quote-message']) || empty($_POST['quote-email']) || !filter_var($_POST['quote-email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        echo json_encode(array('error'=>'true'));
        return false;
    }

    $seguro = $_POST['seguro'];
    $nome = $_POST['quote-name'];
    $email = $_POST['quote-email'];
    $telefone = $_POST['quote-telephone'];
    $mensagem = $POST['quote-message'];

    $subject = ($_POST['subject'] ? $_POST['subject'] : "Novo envio de formulário de contato");


    // Create the email and send the message
    $to = 'contato@ninerscorretora.com.br';// Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
    $email_subject = $subject;
    $email_body = "Tipo de seguro: $seguro <br><br>
                Nome: $nome <br><br>
                E-mail: $email <br><br>
                Telefone: $telefone <br><br>
                Mensagem: $mensagem";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1\r\n".
        "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n".
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n".
        "From: ". $_POST['quote-name'] ." <". $_POST['quote-email'] .">\r\n".
        "Reply-to: ". $_POST['quote-name'] ." <". $_POST['quote-email'] .">\r\n".
        "Date: ". date( "r" );
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    echo json_encode(array('Mensagem enviada com sucesso'));
    return true;            
    ?>
```

Comment: Se me permite, qual a necessidade de 2 formulários? o conteúdo deles são diferentes? não poderia colocar tudo em um único não?

Comment: sim, é um para cada seguro, tem vários na página, se quiser dar uma conferida, http://ninerscorretora.com.br/para_voce.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

acho que há várias formas de fazer isso, eu prefiro assim:

```
<!-- form 1 -->    
<form class="head-quote-seguro" method="post" action="./form-seguros.php?form=Seguro1">
<!-- form 2 -->    
<form class="head-quote-seguro" method="post" action="./form-seguros.php?form=Seguro2">
```

continua usando a classe "head-quote-seguro", só que adiciona os actions que serão chamados no JS, assim:

```
$.ajax({
            type: frm.attr("method"),
            url: frm.attr("action"),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
//evento quando funciona
}})
```

aí no mesmo PHP você pode pegar os respectivos $_GET para separar os formulários ou utilizar urls diferentes no action (eu particularmente prefiro fazer arquivos de submit do php separados para cada formulário).

Legal? Espero ter ajudado. Uso muito assim aqui na www.ecowebdesign.com.br

Abs

Comment: Entendi, então aqui nessa página http://ninerscorretora.com.br/para_voce.html que tem muitos formulários, um para cada box, é bom fazer desse modo?

Comment: É isso aí, faz o JS único chamando o "action" como mostrei e cada modal vai ter seu <form>. Parece que há pouca variação entre os campos, nesse seu caso, eu teria um único submit.php; eu separo quando os formulários são muito diferentes.

Comment: Blz, muito obrigado.

Comment: É nozes. Se for possível dar uns thumbs up aí. Abs e boa sorte